# VS 2008 Issue ->>Unable to start program

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Ok I have a web application in 2005,. net 2.0 , I converted it to 2008  .net 3.5.
when i attempt to run it in VS 2008 either debug or release I get the above mentioned error:

> Unable to start program
>   http:\localhost\MyWebApp

no other message just this. I can access my program directly thru iis and it runs.
It runs on another dev machine correctly.

Any ideas? I have uninstalled and reinstalled v2 several time to no avail.
I also wrote a simple web app, 1 page with a label,  that fails to run also

Need help on this new dev cycle starts soon.

Comment: So, does it fail only when trying to debug with IE, or does it fail with FireFox as your default browser?

Answer (score 2):

Crazy, but may solve the problem. Try this:
Start without debug  (ctrl+F5), and when IE opens, start again in debug mode (F5). 
Dont exit from IE, just stop debug in VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

Your Visual Stuido IDE is not able to link up to the IIS virtual directory. check your project/solution settings and make sure the asp.net website is hosted on local IIS when you are creating the project. Since you are able to access it outside of IIS , it means that the IDE is not able to link the web site with local IIS. Creating a new solution or modifying the solution/project settings should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

Go to the IE Menu tools > Manage complements > disable all of those that you never use.

This works for me! Now IE works better than never before.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the project settings to make sure the web application is still using your local copy of IIS? It may be trying to fire up the VS Web Development Server instead, which is causing you problems.

This could also be flipped, is the project being configured to point to the dev server when it should be IIS?